# Search bar cancel button delegate not called

Tags: ios, swift

I implemented a search bar inside a navigation controller, it's working fine but the cancel button tap delegate method is not being called. Please help:

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
//This function is not being called 
}

let searchBarCnt = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
navigationItem.searchController = searchBarCnt
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
searchBarCnt.delegate = self
searchBarCnt.searchBar.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function delegate is not being called because you are missing the `definesPresentationContext`:

> Determines which parent view controller's view should be presented over for presentations of type
>   UIModalPresentationCurrentContext.  If no ancestor view controller has this flag set, then the presenter
>   will be the root view controller.

you may enable such flag in this way:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print("searchBarCancelButtonClicked")
    }
}
```

---

**Note**: 
without `definesPresentationContext`, you are not really touching the cancel button (when you try to touch it), you are just dismissing the context (you may notice a "silent" glitch in the background focus), suchlike
a popover is being dismissed.

Comment: Note that the `self.definesPresentationContext = true` has to be set after setting the `searchBar`'s `delegate`

Answer (score -2):

When you click the Cancel button which appears next to search bar delegate method won't be called.

Try to click on search button on keyboard and check whether cancel button delegate method is getting called or not