# Swift: Back button should be pressed twice while SearchBar is active

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a UITableViewController embedded in a navigation bar and standard Search bar implementation. I don't hide the navigation bar while the search bar is active. The problem is that while the search bar is active, every button in the navigation bar, like a "Back" button, should be pressed twice— the first time to make the search bar inactive. How can I avoid that? Thank you.

Comment: try to enable the `definesPresentationContext`, check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48090804/2450755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this codes on viewDidLoad

```
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

and add this if your navigationBar is Opaque

```
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```